# Что означает -> в С?

Tags: c

Я понимаю что -> заменяет (*).element для структуры но, изучая чужой код зачастую вижу подобное обращение к функциям и тк в С нет классов это вызывает вопросы.

К примеру:

```
if (chan->write_packed_cell(chan, cell) < 0) {
    goto done;
}
```

-- вызвано внутри той же функции "write_packed_cell"

Извиняюсь за подобный вопрос относящийся больше к теории, но я не часто пишу на С и такое вижу в первые.

Comment: А `goto` не вызывает вопросы?)

Comment: @dIm0n, а что с ним не так? Один из самых понятных операторов :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В структуру можно положить указатель на функцию. Но всё-таки вероятно, `chan` - тоже указатель, так что тут обычное разыменование и обращение:

```
(*chan).write_packed_cell(chan, cell)
```